# Static Reflection Performance

Tags: c#, reflection

I am playing about the static reflection code from Joel Abrahamsson's [blog](http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/invoking-methods-based-on-a-parameter-without-if-else-statements-in-c-sharp) and Daniel Cazzulino's [blog](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/statically-typed-reflection-with-linq/).  But I found their performance is kind of slow, even comparing with refection using "magic string".

```
int iterations = 1000000; 
watch.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    var propertyOfName = Reflect<Employee>.GetProperty(c => c.Name); 
}

watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("[Reflector]: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
watch.Reset();
watch.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    var propertyName = typeof (Employee).GetProperty("Name"); 
}

watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("[Regular Reflection]: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
watch.Reset();
watch.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    var propertyName = StaticReflection.GetMemberName<Employee>(c => c.Name);
}

watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("[StaticReflection]: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
```

Here is the result:

- [Reflector] : 37823
- [Regular Reflection]: 780
- [Static Reflection]: 24362

So why should we prefer Static Reflection? Just remove "magic string"? Or we should add some caching to improve static reflection performance?

Comment: Cache the result of the StaticReflection. If you ask for Employee.Name it will never change during the life-time of that appdomain so caching will be safe.

Comment: this isn't static reflection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason to "prefer" it would be static type checking by the compiler, to ensure you don't make a mess of it (and to ensure it works if you obfuscate, for example). However, IMO it is so rare that a typo here is a *significant* bug (meaning: I'm not including the brain-dead typo you spot and fix during development / unit-testing); so (since I am a performance nut) I typically advise to use the simplest option (`string`). A *particular* example of this is when people are implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface using tricks like this. Just pass a `string` ;p

Comment: Thanks, Marc! it is interesting that Ayende did similar using .NET 2.0 couple years ago. Please see from http://ayende.com/blog/779/static-reflection His conclusion included performance improvement as well by using static reflection. Since his demo code cannot be downloaded any more. I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: @Liang he was probably inspecting the `byte[]` impl directly to get the method-handle - probably noticeably faster than Expression.

Comment: Unfortunately building expression trees are notoriously slow and .NET doesn't cache expression trees automatically. Interestingly enough the overhead of building dynamic expressions in C# (using DynamicObject for instance) is lower than using the Expression<>.

Comment: @Fule I imagine that is a feature of being able to parameterise it arbitrarily. This means they can cache an expression that takes a parameter that is the "capture" class. This can then be reused for all callers. In regular LINQ the signature is pre-defined, so the expression tree must be built each time using.l a ConstantExpression of the capture instance.

Comment: @Fule further: it is the C# compiler, not .NET, that does (or does not do) the expression-tree cache here (but it is .NET via dynamic that caches the IL per resolved type)

Comment: @Marc yes I have considered that a Capture Expression is what is needed as well in order to move the "variables" from the leafs to the root. I was really hoping for that for C#4 but alas no. IMHO the current implementation prohibits the full potential of expression trees.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen http://ayende.com/blog/779/static-reflection ?
He was using just delegates (not expression trees) and had improved compare to normal Reflection performance.

Example of the implementation

```
 public static MethodInfo MethodInfo<TRet, A0>(Func<TRet, A0> func0)
{
        return func0.Method;
}
```